# Transferring videos from Android to iOS Camera Roll

Tags: camera, file-transfer, dropbox, ios

Trying to find the easiest method of getting home videos (up to 3 minutes long) taken on my Nexus 5 (Android) phone and sending it over the internet to the family to save to their iOS (iPhone/iPad) camera roll. Needs to be quite idiot proof on the receiving end (for the family)

Ideally it will compress the video so it doesnt take up too much space as well.

I tried uploading from my Nexus to Dropbox then sending a dropbox link via email so they can open in their Mail app however it will not let you save the video to the camera only view it in Safari.

Comment: It sounds like you need to find out what services and methods on an iPad will let the user save the video instead of just playing it. Once you've found what will work on the iPad end finding an Android app that can use that method will be much easier. It's probably worth asking a variation on this question over at http://apple.stackexchange.com but not asking them about the Android side

Comment: Have you tried with email? I have not tried with email but I can save photos on an iphone from email...

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way is via WhatsApp or any other social networking sites which can send video.

Comment: Can you save videos from whatsapp?

Comment: Yes u can for sure

Comment: Can you save videos from Dropbox? – Yes for sure. But still, that doesn't work for the OP. Trouble isn't the upload, but rather the "receiving end" being unable to save the content.

Comment: Also whatsapp is not available for iPad!